# How do I design a database to track IOUs and payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, accounting

### Question

How do I design a database that can keep track of balances between two users, as well as keep a log of all transactions, without duplicating data?

**Bonus:** Ruby on Rails references will be awesome

#### Details

I'm trying to make a webapp that can keep track of people's IOU's but I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around how to model the database. These are all hard requirements

- Users can owe each other money
  e.g. Alice owes Bob $10
- Users can partially pay back each other money
  e.g. Alice pays $3 back to Bob, and still owes Bob $7
- Users can pay more than owed, and thus become lenders themselves
  e.g. Alice pays Bob $15, and now Bob owes alice $8 (10 - 3 - 15 = -8)
- Users can see a list of users they owe or those who owe them
  e.g Bob owes a total of $10, $8 to Alice, and $2 to Charles
- Users can see a log of their transactions.
  e.g. Alice sent took $10 from Bob, then gave $3 to Bob, and then gave Bob $15

### API

`User` objects have the following methods:

- `User#account_info`: a summary of the user's account

  - **Returns:**

    - `amount_payable`: Amount the user owes
    - `amount_receivable`: Amount the user is owed
- `User#payables`: a list of the people and amounts the user owes

  - **Returns an Array of:**

    - `user`: the other that is owed
    - `amount`: The amount owed
- `User#receivables` a list of the people and amounts the user id owed

  - **Returns an Array of:**

    - `user`: the other that owes us
    - `amount`: The amount owed
- `User#transactions` a list of past transactions:

  - **Returns an Array of:**

    - `type`: `give` or `take`
    - `user`: the other in this transaction
    - `amount`: The amount owed
- `User#give`: give someone money

  - **Params:**

    - `user`: the other in this transaction
    - `amount`: The amount owed
  - **Returns:** `nil`
- `User#take`: take money from someone

  - **Params:**

    - `user`: the other in this transaction
    - `amount`: The amount owed
  - **Returns:** `nil`

### Behavior

Here's how an interactions between users may play out

#### Initial State

```
### Initialize new users
a = User.new
b = User.new
c = User.new

## Users owe and are owed nothing
a.account_info
# {amount_payable: 0, amount_receivable: 0}
b.account_info
# {amount_payable: 0, amount_receivable: 0}

## Users have no payables or receivables
a.receivables
# []
b.receivables
# []

## Users have no transactions
a.transactions
# []
b.transactions
# []
```

#### A Takes $10 from B

```
a.takes(from: b, amount: 10)
# nil

## A now owes $10
a.account_info
# {amount_payable: 10, amount_receivable: 0}
# B is now owed $10
# {amount_payable: 0, amount_receivable: 10}

a.payables
# [{user: b.id, amount: 5}}]
b.receivables
# [{user: a.id, amount: 5}}]


## A has transactions
a.transactions
# [{type: 'take', user: b.id, amount: 10}]
## B has transactions
b.transactions
# [{type: 'give', user: a.id, amount: 10}]
```

#### A gives B $10 back

```
a.gives(to: b, amount: 10)
#nil

# a now owes $5
a.account_info
# {amount_payable: 10, amount_receivable: 0}
# b is now owed $5
# {amount_payable: 0, amount_receivable: 10}

a.transactions
# [{type: 'give', user: b.id, amount: 5}, {type: 'take', user: b.id, amount: 10}]
## B has transactions
b.transactions
# [{type: 'take', user: a.id, amount: 5}, {type: 'give', user: a.id, amount: 10}]

a.payables
# [{user: b.id, amount: 5}}]
b.receivables
# [{user: a.id, amount: 5}}]
```

### Possible solution

(This took me three days and countless headaches)

This solution is extremely hacky

```
def User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :wallet
end

def Wallet << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :accounts
end

def Account << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transfers
  # balance - integer
  # creditor - user_id, class: Wallet
  # debtor - user_id. class: Wallet
end

def Transfer << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  # amount - integer
  # datetime - datetime
end
```

Given the models above:

The magic happens in the `Accounts` model:

- Creditors are owed money when the balance is positive.
- Debtors are owed when the balance is negative.

Transactions are a running log of transfers:

- a positive amount in a transfer means the creditor is sending money to the debtor
- a negative amount is money from the debtor to the creditor.

This way, we determine a user is owed if:

- they're a creditor, and the balance is positive; or
- they're a debtor, and the balance is negative

Comment: Just keep the log and lazily compute the totals on demand.

Comment: What is your specific question, are you stuck on some point in your design? It all seems fairly straightforward the way you set it up. And this is not a Rails question, this is purely a database design problem.

Comment: @Iceman unfortunately, the problem isn't quite that straightforward. Having to calculate individual "payables" and keeping track of the balance of "paying partial back" means I have to create an "account" between two users if it doesn't exist, and then add transactions. I also need to keep track of who's the original creditor, and who's the original debitor, so that I can determine who's "owed" depending whether the balance is positive or negative. My current solution is a headache. I think i'll add it above.

Comment: Yes, definitely add it to the question to clarify.

Comment: @Iceman I've added my solution above.

Comment: @amingilani Are you dead set on the tables you have, or do you still have wiggle room? Honestly I think you are way overly complicating things?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly don't feel like writing out all these queries right now, so I'm just gonna point you in the direction I would go.

First you are overly complicating your tables

```
# Tables:

def User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :wallet
  has_many :transactions
  # General user info
  # wallet_id
end


def Transfers << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creditor (user)
  belongs_to :debtor (user)
  # amount - integer
  # timestamps
  # creditor_id
  # debtor_id
end
```

That is all you need.

You will want to use `ActiveRecord::Base.transactions do` to update your accounts.

Build out a .gives function into your user class.

```
User.gives(to: b, amount: 10)
  # Create transfer 
  # Transfer.create({ amount:10, creditor: a.id, debtor: b.id })
```

Build out a .takes function into your user class.

```
User.takes(from: b, amount: 10)
  # Create transfer 
  # Transfer.create({ amount:10, creditor: b.id, debtor: a.id })
```

Transfers are a simple has many relation

```
User.Transfers
  has_many :Transfers
```

Payables, Receivables, Account_info are a bit more indepth SQL queries but nothing too crazy. Its gonna look something like this (not exactly), and if you cant get it from this comment below. I can come back tonight to try to work these out.

```
a.payables
  # SQL query
  # SELECT  SUM(amount_payable.amount) - SUM (amount_receivable.amount) 
  # FROM User
  # WHERE User = a
  # JOIN Transfer AS amount_payable ON Creditor == a
  # JOIN Transfer AS amount_receivable ON Creditor == amount_payable.debitor
  # GROUPBY amount_payable.debitor
  # HAVING SUM(amount_payable.amount) - SUM (amount_receivable.amount) > 0
```

User.receivables would reverse where Creditor and Debitor are.

Account_Info would double up on the join tables, and have more specific AS statements

Comment: I can see you're tired, but come back tomorrow to clarify. Also, did you mean Transfers are a has many? I actually named them transfers because I didn't want to confuse them with database transactions.

Comment: sorry transactions is transfers. Just edited it.

Comment: @amingilani, do you have any experience with directly working with SQL queries?

Comment: Not really, but I try inferring where I can.

Comment: K will keep that in mind

Comment: Please don't forget that I'm still waiting on you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about RoR, so I can't phrase it in that way. But this is a fairly simple database question. You just need three tables: Users, Loans and Payments. Each loan has a lender and a lendee. Each loan has payments.

The **Users** table just needs a unique ID and information about the user.

The **Loan** table would have two foreign keys to the users table, one for the lender and one for the recipient. This would include the amount of the loan. And it would be created when the money is lent. There could be any number of entries to this table against a single lender or recipient user.

The **Payments** table is just a list of payments against a loan. It has one foreign key link to the loan table. This is the many side of a one-to-many relationship.

So to find out what loans a user has lent you do a query on users and loans and link it on the lender foreign key in loans. Similarly for users that have received loans you use the recipient foreign key.

I would not put a loan balance into the loan table because then you have two sources of truth - the payments table and the loan table. Better to just calculate the remaining loan balance when needed. Relational databases are very good at doing this on very large datasets.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work out very well. I didn't explicitly show it above but I thought it was implied that when you overpay back the loan, you suddenly become the person owed money. With your solution, overpaying back is impossible.

Comment: Once again, it's my fault for not making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is fine, but I would make some adjustments. You don't necessarily need a wallet class unless there are some specific reasons for it. You can just keep track of their balance in the user class itself.

Insides account, instead of having a creditor and debtor id, i would just have 2 user_ids, keep the balance positive, and keep track of who is the one that is owed. This way you don't need to fiddle with negatives, and simplifies a lot of of the bookkeeping.